# Syntax error in c with pow()

Tags: c

Cant figure out the syntax error I'm experiencing, I have the right headers so no idea

```
int get_block_size(int num) {
    int i= 0;

    for (i=0; num < pow(2.0,double(i)); ++i);

    return int(pow(2.0,double(i)));
}
```

The error I am getting

```
sidhuh@ius:~ $ gcc -o b buddy.c
buddy.c: In function `get_block_size':
buddy.c:24: error: syntax error before "double"
buddy.c:24: error: syntax error before ')' token
```

Comment: If you are casting to double, the syntax is `(double)i` not `double(i)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your cast of `i` to `double` is incorrect: in C, you put the type in parentheses, like this:

```
for (i=0; num < pow(2, (double)i); ++i)
    ;
return (int)(pow(2,(double)i));
```

This should fix the syntax error. However, this is not the most efficient - you can get a power of two by shifting `1` left, so instead of writing

```
(int)pow(2, i)
```

you can write

```
1 << i;
```

This works for the same reason that you can obtain `k`-th power of ten in the decimal system by writing `k` zeros after `1`.

Note: it looks like you are trying to round the number up to the nearest larder power of two. There is a "bit twiddling hack" that helps you do it with fewer operations and without the loop. Follow the description [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2).

```
unsigned int v; // compute the next highest power of 2 of 32-bit v
v--;
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
v++;
```

Comment: great help , but for some reason even though it got rid of the syntax error a fatal error appeared 
ld: fatal: file mcrt1.o: open failed: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Student This looks like an error with your make file or the compiler installation, because `mcrt1.o` is a standard library file that ships with the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

int is a type, not a function, so I don't think the compiler likes int(... did you mean a typecast like

```
(int) pow(2.0, (double) i)
```

maybe? That raises other error conditions, but it is at least syntactically correct.